# Detect in Rails after_filter whether we're rendering or redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm writing an after_filter in Rails 3, and I'd like to detect whether or not the controller (or any other filter) has issued a redirect. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could look at the `status` code. 200 is a render, 302 is a redirect.

```
after_filter :what_happened

protected

def what_happened
  was_redirect = self.status == 302
  was_render = self.status == 200
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I could check response.headers['Location'] also.

Comment: There's a whole load of stuff in `self`, worth a look even just out of interest.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is still stuck on rails 3, and wants to use a class based filter to share the logic between controllers with composition, check out the following example:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  after_filter ControllerMetrics
end

class ControllerMetrics
  def self.filter(controller)
    status_xxx = "#{controller.response.status / 100}XX"
    Statsd.increment("response.#{status_xxx}")
  end
end
```